# JPA @OneToMany not persisting/cascading

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, primefaces, persistence, eclipselink

I have the following code in `UserController` in my Session Scoped Bean

```
public void addItemToBundle(ItemEntity item){
    //System.out.println(item.getTitle());
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        UserEntity user = em.find(UserEntity.class, this.username);
        BundleEntity bundle = new BundleEntity();
        BundleEntityPK compositePk = new BundleEntityPK();
        compositePk.setCheckedOutDate(new Date());
        compositePk.setItemId(item.getItemId());
        compositePk.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        bundle.setId(compositePk);
        Set<BundleEntity> bundles = new HashSet<BundleEntity>();
        bundles.add(bundle);
        user.setBundleEntities(bundles);        
        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
    }
}


public String addToBundle(){        
    try {
        addItemToBundle(item);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code uses `private ItemEntity item;` which gets passed in by the following JSF markup:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{itemController.item}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemController.selectedItem}" value="#{movie}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

(I'm using PrimeFaces in this example)  The problem is that the `addItemToBundle` is not calling any SQL code in the console (I have FINE enabled) and the bundle never gets created or added to the user. I also tried `em.persist(user)` and `em.flush()` and setting cascadeType in my UserEntity with no luck.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="userEntity",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<BundleEntity> bundleEntities;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You know that this:

```
try {
    addItemToBundle(item);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

is very bad practice, right? Maybe, that's the problem here, you run into a NPE and never notice it.

You should at least log the exception to know what's going on there (just for demo purposes, I've used stdout, please replace with your favorite logging framework):

```
try {
    addItemToBundle(item);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage()); //use logger here
}
```

Comment: This helped in a way, now I can persist the Bundle but not consistently. Sometimes I have to push the button once, other times it's once, and other times nothing happens..also, is e.printStackTrace() good practice? or no?